# Does FL studio record better audio quality than any any other DAW?

Tags: audio-recording, daw, fl-studio

There are so many daws present in Market, among them are FL, CUBASE, ABLETON LIVE, LOGIC PRO are considered to be higher preferred for many of the music producer. Does different daw gives different auido quality and among them does FL records better audio quality than any other DAW or is this completely a myth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that a Digital Audio Workstation only performs the function of manipulating digital audio samples. Those digital audio samples are "created" by the audio interface. Once the samples have been created, the audio has been 'recorded'. Everything after this point is simply moving numbers around inside a computer and has nothing at all to do with audio quality. Audio quality is going to be determined entirely by the design of the audio interface.